# Karp's definition of constructible hierarchy

Tags: set-theory

In the Karp's paper "A Proof of the Relative Consistency of the Continuum Hypothesis", the successor step of definition of constructible hierarchy is
$$L^*_{\alpha + 1} = \text{set of all subsets of $L^*_\alpha$ of the form $\{x \in L^*_\alpha \mid \phi(x, a_1, \ldots, a_n)\}$} \\ \text{where $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in L^*_\alpha$ and $\phi$ is a $\Sigma_0$ formula in $n + 1$ variables, $n \in \omega$}$$
Comparing with $L_{\alpha + 1} = \operatorname{Def}(L_\alpha)$, $L^*_\beta = L_\beta$ for all limit $\beta$ because $L^*_\alpha \subset L_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ and if $L^*_\alpha = L_\alpha$, $L^*_\alpha \in L^*_{\alpha + 1}$ thus $L_{\alpha + 1} \subset L^*_{\alpha + 2}$.
So with Karp's definition, we simply have a slightly slower hierarchy than the usual one. And I think the condensation lemma also works fine with this version. Is the Karp's definition **strictly** slower?

Comment: If my memory serves me right, given a transitive set $M$, $\operatorname{Def}(M)$ is the smallest transitive set $X$ such that $M\in X$ and $X$ is closed under $\Sigma_0$-separation.